# Xamarin Android Timer Issue

Tags: android, xamarin, timer, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Good morning person,

I created an app that needs a service in the background mounted a time every X. The problem is that it is not available to find a timer that has always ridden in the time that I decided.

I have already tried with: Handler + SendEmptyMessageDelayed, Handler + PostDelayed, ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, System.Threading.Timer, System.Timers.Timer, Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer.

Everyone has the same functioning without initiation, but after a while begins the wheel at different times. There is no test to run it every 3 minutes, usually it runs twice as well and then starts running every 5 minutes, then every 10 minutes and then every 15 minutes or it dies.

Does anyone know a "safe" timer?

Same example code:

```
public void StartPeriodicLocationTask() 
{   
    _timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_token.TempoTransmissao);
    _handler = new Handler(HandlerCallback);
    HandlerCallback(null);

    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduled = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3);
    _runnable = new Java.Lang.Runnable(OnRunTask);
    scheduled.ScheduleWithFixedDelay(
        _runnable
        , 0
        , _token.TempoTransmissao
        , TimeUnit.Seconds
    );

    TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(CheckStatus);
    Timer timer = new Timer(
        timerDelegate
        , 0
        , 0
        , (long)_timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds
    );

    System.Timers.Timer timer2 = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer2.Interval = (long)_timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds; 
    timer2.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    timer2.Enabled = true;


    Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(_timeSpan, () =>
    {
        DebugText debug = new DebugText(
            "Device.StartTimer "
            , 7
        );
        TokenDataBase databaseRunTask = TempDataSource();
        databaseRunTask.SaveDebugTextAsync(debug);
        return true;
    });
}

public static void OnRunTask()
{
    DebugText debug = new DebugText(
        "ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor "
        , 3
    );
    TokenDataBase databaseRunTask = TempDataSource();
    databaseRunTask.SaveDebugTextAsync(debug);
}

public static void HandlerCallback(Message obj)
{
    DebugText debug = new DebugText(
        "HandlerOnRunTask"
        , 4
    );
    TokenDataBase databaseRunTask = TempDataSource();
    databaseRunTask.SaveDebugTextAsync(debug);
}

public static void CheckStatus(Object state)
{
    DebugText debug = new DebugText(
        "System.Threading.Timer"
        , 5
    );
    TokenDataBase databaseRunTask = TempDataSource();
    databaseRunTask.SaveDebugTextAsync(debug);

}

private void OnTimedEvent(
    object sender
    , System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e
)
{
    DebugText debug = new DebugText(
        "System.Timers.Timer"
        , 6
    );
    TokenDataBase databaseRunTask = TempDataSource();
    databaseRunTask.SaveDebugTextAsync(debug);

}
```

Result:
[image: With ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor]

[image: Handler + SendEmptyMessageDelayed]

[image: System.Threading.Timer]

[image: System.Timers.Timer]

Comment: I have tried `System.Threading.Timer` and it worked flawlessly. Would you be able to break it down to a [mcve]? Maybe a form writing out the times with `Debug.WriteLine`?

Comment: I am preparing a example. But the timer work when the cellphone is not in deep sleep.

Comment: Allright, now we are talking. I did not really get that the issue occurred when in deep sleep. Please note that as of Oreo backgrounding is extremely restricted on Android, even if it worked now it's very likely that it will cease to work on an Oreo device, if it is not a foreground service.